# Elasticsearch: filter results having highest field value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have objects with two fields, text and size:

```
{"text":"example text", "size":"0"}
{"text":"some text for example", "size":"1"}
{"text":"other text for example", "size":"1"}
{"text":"example with different size", "size":"2"}
{"text":"just an example", "size":"2"}
```

For example I use `match` query "example" so all objects will be matched. Next I want to filter those of them which have biggest `size` field value which is 2 in this case.

Max value should be taken over matched fields only. So if I search for "text" which will match only first two rows with size 1, objects should be filtered by `size == 1`.

I could get it with two queries, first to get max value, second to filter, but is it possible to do that in one query?

Answer (score 0):

The only option I can think of would be to [sort](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html) the data by your size field:

```
{
  "sort" : [
    { "size" : {"order" : "desc"}}
],
"query" : {
    ...
    }
}
```

Otherwise - yes, you'll need to queries as you describe.

Comment: I can drain results from sorted query and cut them when I have first result with size lower than max value, it works but in such case I have problems with paging and big amount of  matched results.